# Using awk to transpose column to row

Tags: awk

I have an input data file:

```
anim   gent
FZ543     1
FZ543     2
FZ543     3
FZ543     1
FZ547     4
FZ547     3
FZ547     3
FZ547     1
```

I wanted to transpose these data to:-

```
anim     gent
FZ543     1 2 3 1
FZ547     4 3 3 1
```

In other words, I wanted to transpose elements from vertical to horizontal.
I can used AWK Comand

Thanks for your atention.

Comment: It might help to give more context. Are you trying to learn awk? Is it the only program available to you?

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch13_09.htm or does not help?

Answer (score 5):

```
awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}}' file
```

**OUTPUT**

```
anim   gent
FZ543  1 2 3 1
FZ547  4 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '$1 != prev{printf "%s%s",ors,$1; ors=ORS; ofs="\t"} {printf "%s%s",ofs,$2; ofs=OFS; prev=$1} END{print ""}' file
anim    gent
FZ543   1 2 3 1
FZ547   4 3 3 1
```