# Transpose columns to rows in bash

Tags: bash, transpose

I have the following bash command:

```
df -htgfs | awk '{print $5,$4}'| grep "^/"
```

Gives me the following output:

```
/VAULT10 48%
/VAULT11 39%
/VAULT12 59%
/VAULT13 48%
/VAULT14 38%
```

However, I'd like it in the format below:

```
/VAULT10 /VAULT11 /VAULT12 /VAULT13 /VAULT14  
48% 39% 59% 48% 38%
```

But I'm not sure how to achieve it easily in bash (can be space, tab or comma seperated, it's only going to end up being copied/pasted into an excel spreadsheet anyway).

For clarity, the raw df -htgfs output is as follows (this box runs GFS disk clustering).

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pool_gfs-pool_gfs
                      506G  368G  138G  73% /VAULT10
/dev/mapper/pool_gfs1-pool_gfs1
                      506G  202G  304G  40% /VAULT11
/dev/mapper/pool_gfs2-pool_gfs2
                      506G  200G  306G  40% /VAULT12
/dev/mapper/pool_gfs3-pool_gfs3
                      506G  260G  246G  52% /VAULT13
/dev/mapper/pool_gfs4-pool_gfs4
                      506G  237G  269G  47% /VAULT14
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634816/using-awk-to-transpose-column-to-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can take care of that :

```
df -htgfs | awk '$5~/^\//{name=name sep $5; size=size sep $4; sep=","} END{print name; print size}'
```

Comment: That just gives me two blank rows?

Comment: Seeing the output of `df -htgfs`, I understand : I've put a filter on the first caracter of the line to be /, but it should be filtered on the 5th field, see modified command.

Comment: nigh on perfect - one wee question, because I'm actually going to be running this remotely from a windows box, using `plink`: how do I change the output field seperator from space to something else? (the spaces don't showing in the response in `plink` but do through a `putty` session (I've tried slotting in `OFS=","` but clearly in the wrong place.)

Comment: I've put the separator directly in the command, but you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose solution for transposing a file, Bash only.
The file content goes into an array line after line and will be 
written out in another order.

```
declare -a array                    # file content
IFS=' '                             # use $'\t' for tabs
ROWS=0                              # counts rows
COLS=0                              # counts columns

while read -a line ; do
  array+=( ${line[@]} )
  ((ROWS++))
done < "$infile"

COLS=$(( ${#array[@]}/ROWS ))       # get number of column

for (( row = 0; row < COLS; row++ )); do
  line=()
  for (( col = row; col < ROWS*COLS; col += COLS )); do
    line+=( ${array[col]} ) 
  done
  printf "%s\n" "${line[*]}" 
done
```

Comment: I was hoping for something short enough to go on the commandline, as I'm going to be calling this from `plink` on a windows box, but I guess I could make it a two stage process, getting the initial output into a file then calling a bash script per what you've done above, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
df -h | perl -lane \
    'push @n,$F[-1] and push @p, $F[-2] if $#F and $F[-1] =~ m{^/} }{ $, = "\t"; print @n; print @p'
```

Comment: @GrahamGold: Try adding the `tgfs` part back to `df`.

Comment: @GrahamGold: You should probably provide the output of `df -htgfs` as well in your question, as it seems different from what `df` returns on my system.

Comment: Nearly there, edited `df -h` to be `df-htgfs` to only display gfs volumes. However, the order of the vaults is no longer as it was (now showing /VAULT11 /VAULT14 /VAULT10 /VAULT12 /VAULT13)

Comment: @GrahamGold: OK, another update, using arrays instead of hashes.

Comment: Works great. I have one slight issue, but more because of how I'm doing this than anything else. I'm running the command remotely from a windows box using `plink` and with the perl solutions, I keep seeing `SCALAR(0x21345b43)` type entries between each part of each field in the `plink` response that I don't see when I just run the command in a `putty` session.

Comment: @GrahamGold: Maybe a quoting/escaping issue? Not at a MSWin box ATM.